# Text is not changing when is being read

Tags: php

I am trying to create an interactive program where users make  the questions with text boxes  using text files.But i am at a really early stage  where i can create  text file with 2 lines one of them would be the question and the answer.And  i have two php files.One of them create the text files.The other one is supposed to read it and display it on screen when tapped because form action= "questions.php". But for some reason the text displays but does not change

j.php File 1 it is trying to create textfile.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $question1 = $_POST['name'];
    $question2 = $_POST['age'];
    $file = fopen( "question.txt", "w+" ) or die( "file not open" );
    $s = $question1 . "," . $question2 . "\n";
    fputs($file, $s)or die("Data not written");

      }

else{
echo
'<center>
 <form action = "questions.php"  method = "post">
  Question you want ask the person <input  type  = "text" name="name"> <<br>
    Answer<input type = "text" name = "age"><br>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Make Question">
    </form>
    </center>';}
?>
```

expected ouput it makes the file: question.txt

questions.php file2  That is supposed to read and display the newly written data.

```
<?php


$myfile = file_get_contents ("question.txt");
echo $myfile;

?>
```

expected output it is supposed to read the new text

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, but why are you using `w+` mode instead of `w`? I see lots of people using `+` when they open files, but there never seems to be a reason for it. Is it just a bad habit everyone has gotten into because the don't understand what it means?

Comment: Why not use `file_put_contents()` in the first script?

Comment: The browser might be caching the result of the second script, try using a cachebuster in the URL.

Comment: @Bamar I don't know i am using  a chrome browser

Comment: Cachebuster has nothing to do with the browser, it's a a random parameter that you add to the URL. Google it.

Comment: Are you sure the file being written to _is the same file_ which you're trying to read? Could they be in different directories and you're reading a dummy file? I tried your code and it is working if I combine your scripts together.

Comment: Could you please copy/paste/run the following code on your machine and let me if it works for you? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4db52343eb3a5d5b8309fb3bf14120e0fc2e3cf4

Comment: @waterloomatt okay i will try to exceute the both codes in php text editor

Comment: @waterloomatt your code works :)

Comment: Can you please update your question with the physical names of the PHP files and also how you're calling them? I can see your first script is named _questions.php_ and you're accessing it from a form request. What about the 2nd script? Is it in the same directory as _questions.php_?

Comment: @waterloomatt alright just a second sir

Comment: I see the issue. Your form is posting to _questions.php_ which is only reading the file. You're skipping writing to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the updated question, you have 2 files: *j.php* and *questions.php*.

- *j.php* is responsible for displaying the form and also for processing the form.
- *questions.php* is responsible for displaying the contents of the form.

Since your form is posting to *questions.php*, you're skipping over actually processing the form. Just change your form's action to: `action="j.php"` and then redirect to *questions.php* after processing.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $question1 = $_POST['name'];
    $question2 = $_POST['age'];

    $file = fopen( "question.txt", "w+" ) or die( "file not open" );
    $s = $question1 . "," . $question2 . "\n";
    fputs($file, $s)or die("Data not written");

    // Here - redirect to questions.php to display the contents.
    header('Location: questions.php');
    die;
}

<!-- You want to post this form to the processing file. -->
<form action="j.php" method="post">
...
```

Or, simply do everything in a single file.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $question1 = $_POST['name'];
    $question2 = $_POST['age'];

    $file = fopen("question.txt", "w+") or die("file not open");
    $s = $question1 . "," . $question2 . "\n";
    fputs($file, $s) or die("Data not written");

    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    die;
}
?>

<h1>File Writer</h1>

<form method="post">
    <label>
        Question:
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </label><br>

    <label>Answer:
        <input type="text" name="age">
    </label><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Make Question">
</form>

<hr>

The contents of the file are:

<!-- Suppressing a warning here with @. You shouldn't do this. -->
<?php echo @file_get_contents ("question.txt"); ?>
```